Question about the Weak-* Limit of the Incremental Ratio
I am studying Michael E. Taylor's book Measure Theory and Integration and revising Chapter 13 on Radon Measures.
Let $ f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $. Show that the following are equivalent:

(a) $ \frac{1}{h}(\tau_h f - f) $ is bounded in $ L^1(\mathbb{R}) $, for $ h \in (0, 1] $.
(b) $ f' = \mu $ for some finite signed measure $ \mu $ on $ \mathbb{R} $.
(c) $ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \ d\mu $ almost everywhere on $ \mathbb{R} $.

Here is how I approached the implication $ (a) \Rightarrow (b) $:
I observed the following identity:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \cdot \varphi(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \cdot \dfrac{\varphi(x-h) - \varphi(x)}{h} \, dx \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $ C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $ denotes the space of smooth compactly supported functions.
Thus, if the family of functionals $ \dfrac{\tau_h f - f}{h} $ has a weak-* limit in the space of distributions, it must necessarily be the weak derivative $ f' $. By the dominated convergence theorem, the right-hand side converges to $ -\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx $.
Now, since $ \left\{ \dfrac{\tau_h f - f}{h} \right\}_{h \in \mathbb{R}^*} $ is bounded in $ L^1(\mathbb{R}) $, these functionals also act on
$$
C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ \varphi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) : \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \varphi(x) = 0 \right\}.
$$
Indeed, we have
$$
\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \cdot \varphi(x) \, dx \right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \right| \, dx \cdot \|\varphi\|_\infty \\ 
\leq C \cdot \|\varphi\|_\infty,
$$
for some constant $ C $, uniform in $ h $. This inequality shows that $ \dfrac{\tau_h f - f}{h} $ forms a bounded family of functionals on $ C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $. By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, there exists a subsequence that converges weak-* to a measure $ \mu $ in $ C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})^* $, which is the space of finite signed Borel measures. Hence, I should conclude that $ f' = \mu $.
The implication $ (b) \Rightarrow (c) $ follows from an application of Fubini-Tonelli:
$$
-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{x} d\mu(y) \right) \varphi'(x) \, dx 
= -\int_{\mathbb{R}} d\mu(y) \left( \int_{y}^{\infty} \varphi'(x) \, dx \right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(y) \, d\mu(y).
$$
The steps are reversible, so $ (c) \Rightarrow (b) $ is also established.

My question: Could anyone provide a hint on how to prove $ (b) \Rightarrow (a) $?

Due to the somewhat forced "lack of originality" when it comes to give a book a title in this field, it's pretty much always better to forget to tell the title than to forget to provide the author's name; you should see the number of books named "Functional Analysis" or something very adjacent... 1/2

Anyway, I can't access the book by Taylor you are referencing, but the $(c) \Rightarrow (a)$ route might be simpler as long as you've already proved that, if $\mu = g\lambda + \mu_s$ is the Radon-Nikodym decomposition of $\mu$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ then $\lambda$-a.e. : $$\frac{1}{2r}\int^{x + r}_{x-r} \mathrm{d}\mu \xrightarrow[r \to 0^+]{} g(x)$$ or something to that effect in the aforementioned book. Hopefully this will help you. Have a good day/night! 2/2

@BrunoB the convergence is almost everywhere thus the $L^1$ would not be limited.  Also another doubt added up about the equivalence of $(b)$ and $(c).$ If $f = 1$ then $\mu = f' = 0$ then I would get $f = 0.$ What happened?
